# Unknown operator n in Fortran

Tags: debugging, fortran

Program is meant to calculate sqrt of real numbers entered by its user, but rejects calculating complex numbers (in an if statement). User should be able to exit program when he wants. There's an error on `if(dataType.n.real)then`, the build message alert is "Unknown operator n". What am I doing wrong?

```
!square of a number
  real:: x,n
  integer::a
  write (*,*) "1 to continue, or any key to exit: "
  read(*,*)a
  do while(a==1)
    write(*,*)"Type the value of n"
    read(*,*)n
    if(dataType.n.real) then
        x=sqrt(n)
        write(*,*)"x = "
        write(*,*)x
        else
            write(*,*)"Please enter a real number: "
            end if
            write (*,*) "Press 1 to continue, or any key to exit: "
            read (*,*)a
            end do
            stop
            end
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Your indentation is very strange and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

`if(dataType.n.real` is not a Fortran way to compare datatypes and there is no reason to use something like that here. `n` is declared `real` so it is always `real` even if it happens to contain an integer value.

*(High Performance Mark explained in his comment what the compiler sees in `dataType.n.real`, it sees an operator `.n.` applied to two variables `dataType` and `real`. And it complains that it does not know the `.n.` operator and later may complain that it does not know the `dataType` variable either.)*

Fortran is a statically typed language and if you declare  your variable `real :: a`  it is just of type `real` forever. It differs from dynamic languages like Python. If the user tries to input something illegal (for `real`) the `read` statement will fail. That can be controlled by the `iostat=` or the `err=` argument).

```
integer :: ier

read(*,*,iostat=ier) n
if (ier/=0) then
  !invalid input, do what is necessary
end if
```